How do implement fibonacci by gnark，the iteration of n should be a public input
when use gnark implement the fibonacci, i cant iter the public input n，like this:
type Circuit struct {
    A1  frontend.Variable `gnark:",public"`
    A2  frontend.Variable `gnark:",public"`
    N   frontend.Variable `gnark:",public"`
    Res frontend.Variable
}

// Define declares the circuit constraints
// x**3 + x + 5 == y
func (circuit *Circuit) Define(api frontend.API) error {
    n, _ := api.ConstantValue(circuit.N)

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        tmp := api.Add(circuit.A1, circuit.A2)
        api.AssertIsEqual(tmp, api.Add(circuit.A1, circuit.A2))
        circuit.A1 = circuit.A2
        circuit.A2 = tmp
    }
    fmt.Println(circuit.A2)
    api.AssertIsEqual(circuit.Res, circuit.A2)
    //api.AssertIsEqual(a2, circuit.res)
    return nil
}

how do implement fibonacci by gnakr?

Step 1: never actually implement fibonacci as recursive function. There is a closed form expression, implement that instead. Fibonacci is the poster child of "what not to use as example of recursion" because it's an example of a recursive definition only on paper, not if you actually need to program it.

yes，i dont use recursion。but the code cant run，i dont know why。and implement the fibonacci by gnark which appropriate method is ?

Then step back and remove the "fibonacci" part. Just write anything that you can call and returns a fixed, hard coded number.
